# tvos 10 SDK duplicate class implemented in multiple private frameworks causes crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tvos, xcode8, tvos10

I have an tvml app that works great on tvos 9, but when attempting to run on tvos 10.0 simulator the application fails to load and I am presented with a series of errors that begin with:

> class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x11619dd00) **and**
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x115d4a8e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

i'm not using any pods. testing suggests the issue is restricted to tvos 10.0 SDK. how can i resolve a duplicate class conflict in apple's PrivateFrameworks?

Comment: Clean your project.

Comment: project cleaned, no change in behavior.

Comment: Check whether this also occurs on device, and [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: bug has been filed, fingers crossed for quick response.

Comment: I am getting this now too after updating.... :/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by deleting Xcode and then reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I'll got the Same Issue When i Try to copy view and paste another project i'll got same error.

I'll solve the when i'll copy my view i'll find that `Font issue` make sure you must check font included in your project file or use `System Font.`

Than Simple Click on Product and Clean Your Project and Run.

Yehhhh Now No See Any Error...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the info.plist as described in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks)?

That entry describes how to stop the crash, though if you issue is the same root cause, the warning will continue to appear when using the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in an iPhone app. Resetting the iOS simulator fixed this for me. Simulator -> Reset Content And Settings.