# What is causing this XCode 8/iOS 10 compiler warning?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have updated my xcode 8 and running an old app which has been created in 7.3 by convering the swift codes in swift 3. But I am getting the message in  log window as below:

```
   objc[19295]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x118365910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11818f210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
   activity started
```

why its happening ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks)

Comment: My App is Crashing at this Error, I have Set Treat Warnings as Error to No in Build Setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class `PLBuildVersion` declared in your framework `AssetsLibraryServices` as well as in `PhotoLibraryServices`. Because class names are unique Xcode tells you that it will take one of those class declarations, but that it'll keep it a surprise, which one that is. ;)

Luckily, you don't have to be concerned because both classes should be the same.

Comment: its not affecting the app, but its a warning in my log message. how could i remove it?

Comment: Be removing one of the frameworks. :p No really, it's not a problem. I just edited in my answer that you don't have to be concerned, that both classes should be the same.

Comment: ok thats good that I dint need to bother about that one . but still not getting the exact answer.  I dont want the warning at all. so plz if u have idea how to remove the warning  it would be more helpful

Comment: I did give you the answer: You can't get rid of the warning as long as your app uses both frameworks. It's only a warning and is has good reasons to be there. If you don't want to see a warning like this, you must not use (implicit or explicit) two frameworks that both declare the same class. If you do, you really want the compiler to give you some information about that.