# Xcode 8. App freeze at start(on splash screen)

Tags: ios, xcode8

My app freeze at start(on splash screen), even before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

2 questions that may help me:

1- Why do I have all these log on the console, do I have a setting activate to get more logs?

2-How to solve this warning:

> class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x116979910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x1167a3210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Heres what appear on the console:

> objc[53761]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x116979910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x1167a3210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   2016-10-04 19:31:58.143719 p2 DEv[53761:2209717] bundleid:
>   com.aaa.bbbc, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0,
>   propagate_with_activity: 0 2016-10-04 19:31:58.144379 p2
>   DEv[53761:2209717] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents,
>   enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0,
>   debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0,
>   privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0 2016-10-04 19:31:58.151113
>   p2 DEv[53761:2209790] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-10-04 19:31:58.154913
>   p2 DEv[53761:2209790] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-10-04 19:31:58.165802
>   p2 DEv[53761:2209789] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category:
>   MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl:
>   0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0,
>   privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0 2016-10-04 19:31:58.183481
>   pillbox2 DEv[53761:2209717] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0

Comment: Please search on warnings/errors/messages before posting a question. Both of these have been asked before as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can see the answer here to 
   [Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)

   > On your environment variable set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable`
2. The class `PLBuildVersion` is defined in those two frameworks, but seems like it is not your fault.

   > [Radar](http://www.openradar.me/27820992) is already sent

   [Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks/39582284)