# After updating xcode to latest version 8.0 getting undefined PLBuildVersion warning. How to resolve this?

Tags: ios, swift

Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x124349910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x124173210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks)

Comment: Yeah duplicate for sure.