# iOS 10 simulator not working

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode-ui-testing

I have a set of UI automation test cases for my iPhone app.
These tests run fine on the iOS 9 and 8 simulator however when I change to the most recent simulator (10.2) I get this error in my terminal

`objc[8642]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11f55b998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11f37d880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-01-06 10:50:51.918 myAPP[8642:947316] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "gplus://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme gplus"
2017-01-06 10:50:52.142 MyAPP[8642:947316] [Crashlytics] Version 3.7.3 (114)`

Any idea why this is happening? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

The messages you're showing seem to indicate two distinct problems. The first is that you have two definitions of `PLBuildVersion`. The second is the "This app is not allowed to query..." issue.

The likely cause of the second problem is that you need to declare the schemes your app uses in your Info.plist. Use the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and list the schemes you want to look for. Without that, your call to `-canOpenURL:` will fail as you've seen.

The first problem is nicely described in [Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks), and from what I read there it doesn't seem to be anything to worry about.