# ios10 UIImagePickerController crashes randomly. What is the easiest fast fix can be?

Tags: uikit, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, photosframework

When I used UIImagePickerController on ios <= 9, I didn't see any issues. 
On ios 10 I got strange message. I noticed this massage appear after using any code from Photos.framework. (for example checking PHPhotoLibrary status )

> Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x12049a910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x1202c4210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I found similar issue on stackoverflow
[Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks)

I didn't pay attention about it to some moments while I begin get randomly such crash
(about 1 crash on 15-20 using of UIImagePickerController):

[image]

I'm not sure but I think it depend on log message(i.e message above). 
It's sdk bug and issue have opened on Apple Radar.

Here my code for invoking UIImagePickerController:

```
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = allowEditing;
self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
[vc presentViewController: self.imagePicker animated: YES completion: nil];
```

**My main question is:** How can I resolve this issue right now? (Seems like Apple didn't hurry up to resolve it). 
I wouldn't like creating custom image picker (without 100% working guarantee)

Are somebody faced with such issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I decided try open source alternative for UIImagePickerController.

I go through list in this post [How to select Multiple images from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller) and integrated this one [CTAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController).

Log message still appear, but I'm testing it, there are no any issues for now.