# iOS 10 Run Time Crash Error : AssetsLibraryServices and PhotoLibraryServices Not Implemented

Tags: ios

I Haven't Implemented any Class or methods, Just Created on project in XCode got the issue
**My Plist Not Contain Any  AssetsLibraryServices or PhotoLibraryServices**

*Error:*
Class is implemented in both AssetsLibraryServices and PhotoLibraryServices

```
objc[3119]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11ad48cc0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11ab5f6f0).
```

One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

The error appears only when using the iOS 10 Simulator and not showing when using a real device or with 9.3 simulator.

I Have Followed Methods To Overcome Crash Issue:

1. Edited the plist file with
   Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
   Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
2. Changed plist Property List Photo and AssetsLibraryServices as shown below

[image]

3. Found the Path AssetsLibraryServices and Edited Plist

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/

4. Found the Path PhotoLibraryServices and Edited Plist

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/

Even After doing all these i got the same error. Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks)

Comment: "Followed Methods To Overcome Crash Issue:" and "The app builds and run perfectly." which one is it ?

Comment: Warren Burton i have followed methods to overcome the issue.. but can't fix it

Comment: I was asking if you actually had a crash in your application i.e it stops when you don't want it to or if the only problem is that you have a console message.

Comment: My only problem now is console message