# Swift UIWebView doesn't always work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I am currently using **Xcode 8.3.3** and if I'm using a UIWebView I am getting this error you can see down below and then in some projects or some times the WebView doesn't work and in others it does. 
I already testet it with an empty project and yes it is the UIWebView that is causing these issues.

> objc[11182]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11df63cc0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11dd7a6f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Thanks in Advance :)

Edit: also using WKWebView doesn't changed anything. Got still the same issue.

Comment: might [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks), I think it just a warning

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`. It works for me.
Hope this will help you.
[Click here for more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)

Comment: You had the same issue?

Comment: Yes - @meaning-matters

Comment: didnt helped for me.Still the same issue. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have this warning in the app, everytime I access the debugger. 
Seems to be a Xcode issue. 
I use web views in the app but they are not impacted by this warning. 
I think the warning issue and your webview issue are not related