# Swift Error : Classes implemented in two places but files I don't touch?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am testing out swifts UIWebView, I have placed a simple UIWebview on my storyboard and this is my viewController code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsitehere.com")
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))

    } }
```

Unfortunately I am getting this Error below, I have added App transport security settings to my app like other answers to a similar question have said to do but it still isn't working...

Can anyone help?

> objc[946]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x124feecc0) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x124e056f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks/39582284

Comment: Yes I tried these answers but non have worked for me...

Comment: Use `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug with xCode while simulating the real iOS device, some time it through such kind of error. 
Please check whether your url is active or not.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

I used the same code with google URL and it is working.